# Unable to get the value from a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, html, sessionstorage

I have created a JSON object and put it under session object.

How can I retrieve the value from the JSON?

This is my program

```
var datainsession = {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"};

var keyname = 'test';

window.sessionStorage.setItem(keyname + '', datainsession);

var val_sess = window.sessionStorage.getItem(keyname);

var firstname = val_sess.firstName;

alert(firstname);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5bea0mr2/3/

Could you please tell me how I can retrieve the first name?

Comment: its not a json object but whole object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON is represented by a string, not an object. It's simply a JavaScript object with string keys. You'll need to use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` to convert the JavaScript object.

Try the following:

```
var datainsession = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe"
};

var keyname = 'test';

window.sessionStorage.setItem(keyname, JSON.stringify(datainsession));

var val_sess = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem(keyname));

var firstname = val_sess.firstName;

alert(firstname);
```

Answer (score 12):

Session storage can only hold strings, not objects. Your session here ends up holding your object converted to a string (`"[Object object]"`), and not the object itself.

To get around this we can firstly convert the object to a JSON string using `JSON.stringify()`:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem(keyname + '', JSON.stringify(datainsession));
-> '{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}'
```

Then when pulling it convert it back to an object by using `JSON.parse()`:

```
var val_sess = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem(keyname));
-> {"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}
```

Answer (score 5):

`window.sessionStorage.setItem` can only store serialised objects.

So you have to serialise it first via `JSON.stringify`:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem(keyname, JSON.stringify(datainsession))
```

Then to retrieve it via `JSON.parse`:

```
var val_sess = window.sessionStorage.getItem(keyname);
var obj = JSON.parse(val_sess);
// obj.firstName is what you need.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert it to a string on setting, and parse it when you get it out.  This method only stores a string, but JSON methods can get around that.  Eg.

```
var datainsession = {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"};

var keyname = 'test';

 window.sessionStorage.setItem(keyname + '', JSON.stringify(datainsession));

 var val_sess = window.sessionStorage.getItem('test');

var obj = JSON.parse(val_sess).firstName;
```

alert(obj);